# How to group XML records based on field name groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, grouping

I have a requirement wherein i need to read an input XML which has multiple record types( differentiated by a field), and then group these record into different record types based on similar value.

Input XML is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<records>
  <record>
    <empID>80000000</empID>
    <code>10</code>
    <Date>2019-01-23</Date>
    <FieldName>A</FieldName>
    <NewIDorValue>C HACIENDA DEL PEÃ‘ASCO 1271</NewIDorValue>
  </record>
  <record>
    <empID>80000000</empID>
    <code>10</code>
    <Date>2019-01-23</Date>
    <FieldName>A</FieldName>
    <NewIDorValue>400</NewIDorValue>
  </record>
  <record>
    <empID>80000000</empID>
    <code>10</code>
    <Date>2019-01-23</Date>
    <FieldName>B</FieldName>
    <NewIDorValue>PLAZAS DEL SOL1</NewIDorValue>
  </record>
  <record>
    <empID>80000001</empID>
    <code>10</code>
    <Date>2019-01-23</Date>
    <FieldName>B</FieldName>
    <NewIDorValue>Querétaro</NewIDorValue>
  </record>
  <record>
    <empID>80000000</empID>
    <code>10</code>
    <Date>2019-01-23</Date>
    <FieldName>A</FieldName>
    <NewIDorValue>76091</NewIDorValue>
  </record>
    <record>
    <empID>80000001</empID>
    <code>10</code>
    <Date>2019-01-23</Date>
    <FieldName>B</FieldName>
    <NewIDorValue>76091</NewIDorValue>
  </record>
</records>
```

I want to group the records based on FieldName, output XML should be

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Data>
<records>
  <record>
    <empID>80000000</empID>
    <code>10</code>
    <Date>2019-01-23</Date>
    <FieldName>A</FieldName>
    <NewIDorValue>C HACIENDA DEL PEÃ‘ASCO 1271</NewIDorValue>
  </record>
  <record>
    <empID>80000000</empID>
    <code>10</code>
    <Date>2019-01-23</Date>
    <FieldName>A</FieldName>
    <NewIDorValue>400</NewIDorValue>
  </record>
  <record>
    <empID>80000000</empID>
    <code>10</code>
    <Date>2019-01-23</Date>
    <FieldName>A</FieldName>
    <NewIDorValue>76091</NewIDorValue>
  </record>
  </records>
<records>
  <record>
    <empID>80000000</empID>
    <code>10</code>
    <Date>2019-01-23</Date>
    <FieldName>B</FieldName>
    <NewIDorValue>PLAZAS DEL SOL1</NewIDorValue>
  </record>
  <record>
    <empID>80000001</empID>
    <code>10</code>
    <Date>2019-01-23</Date>
    <FieldName>B</FieldName>
    <NewIDorValue>Querétaro</NewIDorValue>
  </record>
  <record>
    <empID>80000001</empID>
    <code>10</code>
    <Date>2019-01-23</Date>
    <FieldName>B</FieldName>
    <NewIDorValue>76091</NewIDorValue>
  </record>
</records>
</Data>
```

I understand that it can be done easily using XSLT but I have to achieve this using Groovy. Please advise if this can be done by Groovy? Please note, the field "FieldName" values are not sorted.

Using following code i was able to sort the records alphabetically but not sure how to group those

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.InputStream;
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder;
import org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter;

for( int i = 0; i < dataContext.getDataCount(); i++ ) {
    InputStream is = dataContext.getStream(i);
    Properties props = dataContext.getProperties(i);

def rootNode = new XmlParser().parse(is);

        def writer = new StringWriter()
        def mkp = new MarkupBuilder(writer)

        mkp.records{
            rootNode.children()
                    .sort{it.FieldName.toString()}
                    .each{ e ->
                        record {
                            empID(e.empID.text())
                            code(e.code.text())
                            Date(e.Date.text())
                            FieldName(e.FieldName.text())
                            NewIDorValue(e.NewIDorValue.text())
                        }

                    }
        }

XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter();
is = new ByteArrayInputStream(writer.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

dataContext.storeStream(is, props);
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you've tried, but it should work to read these in (XMLSlurper or similar), sort the resulting structure by field, then output it again.  Are you asking specifically how to do this?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I was able to sort the records. However i am not sure how to group the all A records. Do i need to loop through all the records nd then add one by one?

Answer (score 2):

Groovy is sometimes too easy... Just use `groupBy` instead of sorting your records.

```
rootNode.children().groupBy{it.FieldName.toString()}.each{ group, recs ->
    records {
        recs.each{ e ->
            record {
                empID(e.empID.text())
                code(e.code.text())
                Date(e.Date.text())
                FieldName(e.FieldName.text())
                NewIDorValue(e.NewIDorValue.text())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`groupBy` creates a `Map` with the grouping criteria as keys and a `List` of all matching elements as values.

```
def data = [
    [a:"A", b:"foo"],
    [a:"B", b:"bar"],
    [a:"A", b:"wasd"],
    [a:"B", b:"esdf"]
]

assert data.groupBy{it.a} == [
        A:[
            [a:"A", b:"foo"],
            [a:"A", b:"wasd"]
        ],
        B:[
            [a:"B", b:"bar"],
            [a:"B", b:"esdf"]
        ]
    ]
```